# как между "" вставить \\ в PHP

Tags: php

```
$music_del = "..\\..\\bands\\".$BN."\\music\\".$AN;
```

\\ экранируют друг друга

как правильно их прописать?

Comment: экранируйте каждую

Comment: прописать вроде \\\\ ?

Comment: да, прописать вроде \\\\

Comment: если \\\\ они попарно экранируют друг друга
если \\\ экранируется кавычка

Comment: ну так вы же и хотели их попарно экранировать

Comment: мне нужно прописать путь для FileSystemObject в php

Comment: ну так в чем проблема? вы получаете какую-от ошибку или что? с чего вы взяли что вам нужно что-то экранировать?

Comment: не находит директорию

Comment: а вы уверены что директория которую вы ищете - действительно есть?

Comment: может быть ошибка с уровнем, либо значениям BN или AN

Comment: всё разобрался, всем спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А зачем, когда можно так

```
$music_del = '..\..\bands\'.$BN.'\music\'.$AN;
```

и вместо `\` лучше использовать `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` константа разделение директории в linux это `/`, а в windows это `\`.

Comment: в windows и так и так можно

Comment: там двойная \\ нужна

Comment: как это можно проаисать?

Comment: Зачем двойная? Если двойная так и пиши только в ординарной ковычке, но вопрос актуальный зачем двойная...
п.с. какая разница как можно, надо делать как нужно. это Grundy